# ERROR: syntax error at or near "END"

Tags: postgresql, trigger, syntax, postgresql-13

I am trying to play around with trigger and found some samples online which I pretty much copied before except changed table name and row counts.  But somehow I kept on getting syntax error and function does not exist.

I thought it has to be with schema since you can see below the the table has a schema name of public so I added public when create and provoking the `check_number_of_row()` but still getting errors.  I removed the schema `public` from the code already since it doesn't help too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_number_of_row()
RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN

    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM public.comment) > 3
    THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'INSERT statement exceeding maximum number of rows for this table' 
   END IF;
END;$$;  -- this is the syntax END error happened


CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_number_of_row 
BEFORE INSERT ON public.comment
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_number_of_row();  -- this is where it says function does not exist
```

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.4
```

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact error returned is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
LINE 9:    END IF;
           ^
```

Your `RAISE EXCEPTION` statement needs to be terminated with a semicolon:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_number_of_row()
RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN

    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM public.comment) > 3
    THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'INSERT statement exceeding maximum number of rows for this table';
   END IF;
END;$$;
```

Comment: omg! thank you so much! I copied it from other posts and didn't even realize that....thx thx thx